# Finding the expected value $E(|-3X+8|)$ knowing $E(X) = -0.5$.

Tags: probability, expectation

How can I find $E(|-3X+8|)$ knowing $E(X)=-0.5$? How should I approach this? Can I just find $|-3EX+8|$?

Comment: Why do you write $|2x-5x+8|$ instead of $|8-3x|$?

Comment: Oh, sorry! But it doesn't change the problem, right?

Comment: No, $E(|-3X+8|)$ is not $|-3EX+8|$. You can deduce the latter from the fact that $E(X)=-0.5$ but you cannot compute the former. At most, you can say that $E(|-3X+8|)\geqslant|-3EX+8|$.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It just looked odd.  To your question:  it is not determined.  Try, for example, the case when $X=-.5$, a constant or when $X=\{-4,3\}$ with equal probability.

Comment: So, does it mean that I'm only able to find the answer when I have been a  given particular distribution table?

Comment: Basically, yes.  If it helps, the mean is $9.5$ if the support of $X$ is fairly near $-.5$.  Informally, you just want $8-3X$ to stay  positive for all values of $X$ (so the absolute value doesn't change anything).  Otherwise, you need more information.